# Send and recieve parameter with ajax using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm tring to send and receive parameters with AJAX without any sucess

First I choose AREA and than the CITIES in this area.

Can you please tell me what do I do wrong?

Client side:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#first").click( 

    function(){

        var area_id=$("#area_id").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recs.php",
        data: "area_id="+area_id,
        cache:false,
        success: 
          function(data){
            $("#second").html(data.message); 
          }

        });

      return false;

    });


});


</script>


<form method="post" action="tosomewhere.php">

    <select id="first" name="area_id">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="second" name="section">  </select>

</form>
```

Server Side:

```
$areaID = $_POST['area_id'];
$second_option = "";

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE area_id = $areaID ORDER BY id ASC");
while($index = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) 
{
    $id = $index['id'];
    $name  = $index['name'];

    $second_option .= "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";
}

echo $second_option;
exit;
```

Thank you in advanced

**After editing:**

I changed the code to something even simpler:

Client side:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#first").click( 
    function(){
        var area_id=$("#area_id").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "recs.php",
        data: "area_id="+area_id,
        cache:false,
        success: 
          function(data){
            $("#second").html(data); 

          }

        });

      return false;

    });


});


</script>

<form method="post" action="tosomewhere.php">

    <select id="first" name="area_id">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <div id="second"></div>

</form>
```

Server side:

```
some text
```

I'm still not getting the string into

Comment: What is wrong? retrieve some error in your console?

Comment: I found this nice tuto, so i share it with you http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "without success"?  What happens when your code runs?

Comment: Second SELECTBOX doesn't fiiled with data...@AleksG

Comment: maybe I didn't build the ajax script right...?

Answer (score 3):

change

```
$("#second").html(data.message);
```

to

```
$("#second").html(data);
```

Comment: I'm still not getting respond from the server side.
I tried to type simple string instead of the SQL query, and it's still not send to the client side...

Comment: Use `echo '<option>test</option>';` instead of `echo $second_option;`. If you see that then the problem is in your mysql query.

Comment: Please check again my first post.

I edited it and add new simple code (After editing:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug code where is actually fault whether you ajax call is actually initialize.

i: check whether value properly fetch in "area_id" js variable

```
alert(area_id);
```

ii: if it ok check whether data proper returned from server scriptinog

```
alert(data); or alert(data.message);
```

iii: for testing whether you receive data properly, just send out test script.

```
echo "sample text";
exit;
```

or try to send data in json format

```
die('{"message" : "sample text"}');
```

If all three steps working, then there should be fault in data access script.

If you are not getting output in ajax try using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to check what is actually happening in sending request and getting response.

Comment: Please check again my first post.

I edited it and add new simple code (After editing:)

Comment: use firebug to track what is actually happening when ajax call initialize.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#first").click(function(){
        var area_id=$("#area_id").val();
        $("#second").load('tosomewhere.php?area_id=' + area_id);
      return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Changed the jquery a bit. Using GET.

Also the script has changed:

```
$areaID = (int) $_GET['area_id'];
$second_option = "";

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE area_id = '$areaID' ORDER BY id ASC");
if (mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0){    
    while($index = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
        $second_option .= '<option value="'.$index['id'].'">'.$index['name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo $second_option;
} else {
    echo 'No result!';
}

die();
```

Added (int) before $_GET as a pre-security measurement.

Comment: I'm still not getting respond from the server side.
I tried to type simple string instead of the SQL query, and it's still not send to the client side...

Comment: make sure tosomewhere.php?area_id is pointing to the same directory. Try to add the full path to the script first. Then try this string in your browser:
tosomewhere.php?area_id=5

You should get a response. If you dont, then something is wrong in your php script

Comment: Try the new serverscript, it will echo something even if there is something wrong with your query

Comment: Please check again my first post.

I edited it and add new simple code (After editing:)

Comment: Try opening F12 in your browser. Go to the network tab and click on the #first. You should see a new request appear. If it is in red, it means that the request url is not correct. If it is not red, you can check the response somewhere there too. I have tried your new script and mine and they are both working. I think the path is not pointing to your server script

Comment: This -> var area_id=$("#area_id").val(); is not correct either. You should use var area_id=$("#first").val(); There is no id called area_id. It is a name field and that name field is property to #first

Comment: Do you have this script online somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter to the ajax function

```
dataType:'text'
```

Comment: done, but still not getting the string form the php file (server side)